# C++ Check if char has "P" unicode category

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to rewrite in C++ the following Python code:

```
cat = unicodedata.category(char)
if cat.startswith("P"):
    return True
```

ChatGPT says that I need ICU (International Components for Unicode) library to do that, which I don't like, since it's not header only and I don't want additional dependencies. Is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything in the standard library for that. Unless you know how to do it from the raw bytes, you'll need something third-party.

Comment: Unicode category is essentially a lookup table. For all millions of Unicode characters. Some tricks are typically used to reduce and optimize the category lookup. Now that you understand  what this really is, do you still believe that shoving such a hairball into a standalone header file makes a lot of sense?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly ChatGPT is correct in this instance. You need an additional library to handle this and ICU is the most complete solution.

C++ does not include the Unicode Character Database or anything operating on its contents in the standard library.

Even if you were to implement the functionality yourself, you would still need to include the database itself as a dependency anyway (and that would hardly be possible as header-only). Python just includes a copy.